# Remove an HTML node with Floki

Tags: elixir

I want to remove an HTML node with [Floki](https://hexdocs.pm/floki/Floki.html). But it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

```
iex(17)> Floki.find(html_doc, "div.xyz")
[
  {"div", [{"class", "xyz"}],
   [
     {"p", [],
      ["foobar"]}
   ]}
]
iex(18)> Floki.find_and_update(html_doc, "div.xyz", fn _ -> "" end)
** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: ""
    (floki 0.34.0) lib/floki.ex:350: anonymous fn/2 in Floki.find_and_update/3
    (elixir 1.14.3) lib/enum.ex:1658: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (floki 0.34.0) lib/floki.ex:348: Floki.find_and_update/3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation on [`Floki.find_and_update/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/floki/Floki.html#find_and_update/3) clearly states, the successful typing would be

```elixir
 ({String.t(), [html_attribute()]} ->
     {String.t(), [html_attribute()]} | :delete)
) :: html_tree()
```

and

> If fun returns `:delete`, the HTML node will be removed from the tree.

That said, the following should work.

```elixir
Floki.find_and_update(html_doc, "div.xyz", fn _ -> :delete end)
```